# Include Id with ajax post

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I'm stuck at this part...
I'm trying to get the ID to be included when AjaxPost sends it to the server, but I can't quite find the right information when I looked it up.
I have a set of html inputs that have  an id. They all have a button that appears next to them on `keypress`, and when I click this button, it saves the value and ajax sends it to the server. I got the value in the textbox to be included, but I can't seem to get the id of that text box into the `post`.

*Here is my Ajax function*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.solo1').after('<span class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-icon-disk ui-icon saveButton" onClick="save();" title="Save" style="float:left; height:20px;" onclick="save()"></span><br />')// ui icon
    .keypress(function() {
        $(this).next('.saveButton').show();//appends ui icon
    });

$('.saveButton').hide().click(function() {
    $(this).hide(); // removes ui icon on click
});

$('.ui-state-default').hover(
    function () { $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover'); },
    function () { $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover'); } //ui icon hover
);
});
function save(value) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "Default.aspx",
    type: "POST",
    data: "{ Id: " + $(".solo1").attr('id') + ", Value: " + $(".solo1").val() + "}",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);

        },
    });
}
</script>
```

*--HTML--*

```
<div id="featherbone">
<input class="solo1" id="craven1"/>
<input class="solo1" id="craven2"/>
<input class="solo1" id="craven3"/>
<input class="solo1" id="craven4"/>
<input class="solo1" id="craven5"/>
</div>
```

Here's what the firebug post reads..

```
{ Id: , Value: [value entered into textbox]}
```

As you see, the id is excluded
*Thanks in advance..*

Comment: What's the value of `id`? `.text()` will always return the text content of an element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I fixed it.. Made variables within the ajax call's scope, and used the variables in the data.

```
    $('.saveButton').click(function () {
        var id = $(this).prev().attr('id'); //used in the "data" attribute of the ajax call
        var value = $(this).prev().val(); //used in the "data" attribute of the ajax call

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx",
            data: "{Id: " + id + ", Value: " + value + "}",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
        $(this).hide();
    }); //runs ajax call and removes ui-icon after .saveButton is clicked
```

Another issue I was having, is that it will only get the value and id of the first text box.. and not the rest of them.. I found out that `.prev()` (entered in the "id" and "value" variables) is necessary to go around this setback.
Code on!

Answer (score 2):

Try changing this:

```
  data: "{ Id: " + $(".solo1").attr('id') + ", Value: " + $(".solo1").val() + "}",
```

Although now that I look back it occurs to me that you will have odd behavior like this.

You initial problem is that id is not defined. It is out of the scope of your function it seems.

You can do something like this before the ajax call...

```
var id = null;
$('.solo1').each(function(){
    if($(this).val() != '')
    {
        id = $(this).attr('id');
    }
});
```

But again, this is more of a dirty work around for what you're actually trying to do here.

Comment: Hmmm.. It got the Id in there, but it only posts the first id (craven1) for all the posts.. Give me a sec, gonna update the content to show how I have my javascript set up

Comment: That's the odd behavior I was talking about. Calling $(".solo1").val()  is a bad idea since technically all of those input fields have a value, even if you don't define it. So it will always give the results of the first one found. I can update with an option - albeit a bad practice - for selecting the value while preserving this html structure...

Comment: But when I enter something in the textbox and save it, it will post the value that i entered to the textbox with id craven1/2/ and so on. It has those different values i entered, but it still posts the craven1 id for them all.. if that makes any sense

Comment: They're different selectors with different rules. .val() may stop at the first occurrence of a non empty value. .attr('id') will get the first one with an id attr regardless of the value. My update may get past that since it assigns a var to the input object with a non empty value.

Comment: I was mistaken.. You are right. It enters the same value for id="craven1" for all the text boxes.. Looks like back to the drawing board for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div id="featherbone">
<input class="solo1" data-id="craven1"/>
</div>
```

Then in your jQuery:

```
data: "{ Id: " + $(".solo1").attr("data-id") + ", Value: " + $(".solo1").val() + "}",
```